# How to remove merged Geometry

Tags: performance, three.js, geometry

For performance reasons I merged geometry. I have tens of thousands of cubes to display. I have that working with reasonable performance.

Now I have to deal with removing some. I almost have it but can't figure out how to make this work, so I cut my code up to make this complete sample.

In the `onDocumentMouseDown` function when a cube is clicked on I try to remove it. And it sort of does. But instead of removing *one* cube it removes *two*. (Then it basically acts worse) It removes the one I pointed at and the next one I added.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Measurement</title>
  <style>
   body { margin: 0; }


  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="canvas_container" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px; touch-action:none;"></div>

  <div id="MessageDisplay1" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;  background-color: black; opacity: 0.8; color:white; touch-action:none;"></div>

  <div id="MessageDisplay" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 200px;  background-color: black; opacity: 0.8; color:white; touch-action:none;"></div>

    <script src="js/three.js"></script>

    <script>


   // player motion parameters
   var motioncontrol = {
    airborne: false,
    bumpposition: 5.0,
    bumpdegrees: 4.0,
    rotationanglezx: 0,
    tiltangle: 0,
    distancePointZ : 10000.0,
    distancePointY: 100.0,

    position : new THREE.Vector3(), velocity : new THREE.Vector3(),
    rotation: new THREE.Vector3(), spinning: new THREE.Vector2(),
    prevposition : new THREE.Vector3(),
    prevrotation : new THREE.Vector3()
   };

  var mouseDown = 0;
  var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
  var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  var INTERSECTED;

  motioncontrol.position.y = 15;
  motioncontrol.position.x = 0;
  motioncontrol.position.z = 0;
  motioncontrol.rotation.x = 0;

  motioncontrol.rotation.z = motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.cos(0);
  motioncontrol.rotation.x = motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.sin(0);

  motioncontrol.prevposition.copy(motioncontrol.position);
  motioncontrol.prevrotation.copy(motioncontrol.rotation);

  // Our Javascript will go here.
  var domContainer = null;
  domContainer = document.getElementById("canvas_container");           
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 5000 );
  var aspectratio = window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  domContainer.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  var materials = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture/sky.jpg');

  addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  domContainer.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
  domContainer.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);

  var scene = new THREE.Scene();

  scene.add(camera);
  window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);
  camera.position.x = 0;
  camera.position.y = 100;
  camera.position.z = -100;
  camera.rotation.y = Math.PI / 180.0 * 90;


  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
  directionalLight.position.set(0, -10, 0);
  scene.add(directionalLight);


  directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 3.0);
  directionalLight.position.set(0, -50,-1000);
  scene.add(directionalLight);

  directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 3.0);
  directionalLight.position.set(0, -50, 1000);
  scene.add(directionalLight);


  directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 3.0);
  directionalLight.position.set(-200, -10, 0);
  scene.add(directionalLight);


  directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 3.0);
  directionalLight.position.set(200, -10, 0);
  scene.add(directionalLight);


  addGround(scene);

  // array of unsorted geometries.
  var CubeGeometryArray = new Array();
  var CubeGeometryTier1 = new THREE.Geometry();
  var CubeGeometryTier2 = new THREE.Geometry();
  var CubeGeometryTier3 = new THREE.Geometry();
  var CubeGeometryTier4 = new THREE.Geometry();
  var CubeGeometryTier5 = new THREE.Geometry();

  // array of materials
  var CubeMaterials = new Array();

  // array of meshes used for hit testing. 
  var CubeArray = new Array();
  var cMaterialCount = 0;
  var Cube20Mesh;
  var Cube40Mesh;
  var CubesLoaded = false;

  LoadCubeMaterial();
  LoadCubeMeshs();
  var controls;


  function resize()
   {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
   };

  function onMouseWheel(event)
   {
    var delta = 0;

    if ( event.wheelDelta !== undefined ) {
     // WebKit / Opera / Explorer 9
     delta = event.wheelDelta;

    } else if ( event.detail !== undefined ) {
     // Firefox
     delta = - event.detail;
    }

    if ( delta > 0 ) {  // forward  

      var angle = Math.atan2(motioncontrol.rotation.x, motioncontrol.rotation.z);        
      motioncontrol.position.z += motioncontrol.bumpposition * Math.cos(angle);
      motioncontrol.position.x += motioncontrol.bumpposition * Math.sin(angle);                            

    } else if ( delta < 0 ) {

      var angle = Math.atan2(motioncontrol.rotation.x, motioncontrol.rotation.z);
      angle += Math.PI;
      motioncontrol.position.z += motioncontrol.bumpposition * Math.cos(angle);
      motioncontrol.position.x += motioncontrol.bumpposition * Math.sin(angle);

    }
   };

  function onDocumentMouseMove(event)
   {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (mouseDown > 0) {
     if (((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1) > mouse.x) {
      motioncontrol.rotationanglezx -= motioncontrol.bumpdegrees;
      if (motioncontrol.rotationanglezx < 0)
       motioncontrol.rotationanglezx += 360;

      var angle = (Math.PI / 180.0) * motioncontrol.rotationanglezx;
      motioncontrol.rotation.x = motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.cos(angle) - motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.sin(angle);
      motioncontrol.rotation.z = motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.sin(angle) + motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.cos(angle);

     }

     if (((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1) < mouse.x) {
      motioncontrol.rotationanglezx += motioncontrol.bumpdegrees;
      if (motioncontrol.rotationanglezx > 360)
       motioncontrol.rotationanglezx -= 360;

      var angle = (Math.PI / 180.0) * motioncontrol.rotationanglezx;
      motioncontrol.rotation.x = motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.cos(angle) - motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.sin(angle);
      motioncontrol.rotation.z = motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.sin(angle) + motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.cos(angle);
     }
    }
   };

  function onDocumentMouseDown(event)
   {
    ++mouseDown;
    event.preventDefault();
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

    intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(CubeArray);
    if(intersects.length > 0)
     {
      if(intersects[0].object.name != null)
       {
        var offset = intersects[0].object.name * 8;
        var offsetfaces = intersects[0].object.name * 12;
        var index = intersects[0].object.name;
        var selectedObject = scene.getObjectByName("Tier1");
        scene.remove(selectedObject);

        CubeArray.splice(index, 1);
        CubeGeometryTier1 = CubeGeometryArray[0];
        CubeGeometryTier1.vertices.splice(offset, 8);
        CubeGeometryTier1.faces.splice(offsetfaces, 12);
        CubeGeometryTier1.faceVertexUvs[0].splice(offsetfaces, 12);

        CubeGeometryArray[0] = CubeGeometryTier1.clone();

        CubeGeometryTier1.sortFacesByMaterialIndex();
        var cmesh = new THREE.Mesh(CubeGeometryTier1,   new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(CubeMaterials));
        cmesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
        cmesh.updateMatrix();
        cmesh.name = "Tier1";
        scene.add(cmesh);
       }
      else
       INTERSECTED = null;
     }
   };

   function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {
       mouseDown = 0;
       event.preventDefault();                       
   }

  function addGround(scene1)
   {
    var materialg =  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x333333 , side: THREE.BackSide } );    
    var groundmesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(9000, 4500, 1), materialg);
    groundmesh.receiveShadow = true;
    groundmesh.rotation.x = Math.PI / 180.0 * 90;
    groundmesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    groundmesh.name = "asphalt";
    scene1.add(groundmesh);
  };

  function writeToScreen(message)
   {
    var pre = document.getElementById("MessageDisplay");
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
    pre.innerHTML = message;
   }


  function writeToScreen2(message)
   {
    var pre = document.getElementById("MessageDisplay1");
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
    pre.innerHTML = message;
   }


  function addCube20(name, x1,z1,azimuth,height,add)
   {
    var cube;
    if (add)
     {
       if (height > 5)
        height = 5;
       cube = Cube20Mesh.clone();
       cube.visible = true;
       cube.receiveShadow = true;
       cube.position.set(x1, ((height - 1) * 8.5) + 4.25, z1);
       cube.rotation.y = (Math.PI / 180.0) * azimuth;
       cube.name = name;
       cube.updateMatrix();
       AddCubeGeometry(cube.geometry, cube.matrix, height);
       cube.matrixWorld = cube.matrix;
       CubeArray.push(cube); // kept for hit test
      }
   };

  function addCube40(name, x1, z1, azimuth,height,add)
   {
     var cube;
     if (add)
     {
       if (height > 5)
         height = 1;
        cube = Cube40Mesh.clone();
        cube.visible = true;
        cube.receiveShadow = true;
        cube.position.set(x1, ((height - 1) * 8.5) + 4.25, z1);
        cube.rotation.y = (Math.PI / 180.0) * azimuth;
        cube.name = name;
        cube.updateMatrix();
        AddCubeGeometry(cube.geometry, cube.matrix, height + 5);
        cube.matrixWorld = cube.matrix;
        CubeArray.push(cube); // kept for hit test
       }
    };

  function LoadCubeMeshs()
  {
   var CubeGeometry20 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 8.5, 9.5);
   var CubeGeometry40 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(40, 8.5, 9.5);
   Cube20Mesh  = new THREE.Mesh(CubeGeometry20);
   Cube40Mesh =  new THREE.Mesh(CubeGeometry40); 
   CubesLoaded = true;
  };


  function LoadCubeMaterial()
  {
   CubeMaterials[0] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0000 });
   cMaterialCount++;
   CubeMaterials[1] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffff00 });
   cMaterialCount++;
   CubeMaterials[2] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffffff });
   cMaterialCount++;
   CubeMaterials[3] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x0000ff });
   cMaterialCount++;
   CubeMaterials[4] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00ffff });
   cMaterialCount++;
   CubeMaterials[5] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x772255 });
   cMaterialCount++;
   CubeMaterials[6] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x552277 });
   cMaterialCount++;
   CubeMaterials[7] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x222299 });
   cMaterialCount++;
   CubeMaterials[8] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x992222 });
   cMaterialCount++;
   CubeMaterials[9] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x000000 });
   cMaterialCount++;
   };


       function DisplayCubes(scene1)
        {
          if(CubeGeometryTier1.faces.length > 0)
          {
           var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
            // save the unsorted geometry. 
            CubeGeometryArray.push(CubeGeometryTier1.clone());
            CubeGeometryTier1.sortFacesByMaterialIndex();
            var Cubemesh = new THREE.Mesh(CubeGeometryTier1, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(CubeMaterials)); 
            Cubemesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
            Cubemesh.updateMatrix();
            Cubemesh.name = "Tier1";
            scene1.add(Cubemesh);
           }

          if(CubeGeometryTier2.faces.length > 0)
           {
            // save the unsorted geometry. 
            CubeGeometryArray.push(CubeGeometryTier2.clone());
            // sorting is a HUGE performance boost 
            CubeGeometryTier2.sortFacesByMaterialIndex();
            var Cubemesh = new THREE.Mesh(CubeGeometryTier2,  CubeMaterials); 
            Cubemesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
            Cubemesh.updateMatrix();
            Cubemesh.name = "Tier2";
            scene1.add(Cubemesh);
           }

          if(CubeGeometryTier3.faces.length > 0)
           {
             CubeGeometryArray.push(CubeGeometryTier3.clone());
             CubeGeometryTier3.sortFacesByMaterialIndex();
             var Cubemesh = new THREE.Mesh(CubeGeometryTier3, CubeMaterials); 
             Cubemesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
             Cubemesh.updateMatrix();
             Cubemesh.name = "Tier3";
             scene1.add(Cubemesh);
            }

          if(CubeGeometryTier4.faces.length > 0)
          {
             CubeGeometryArray.push(CubeGeometryTier4.clone());
             CubeGeometryTier4.sortFacesByMaterialIndex();
             var Cubemesh = new THREE.Mesh(CubeGeometryTier4,   CubeMaterials); 
             Cubemesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
             Cubemesh.updateMatrix();
             Cubemesh.name = "Tier4";
             scene1.add(Cubemesh);
            }

          if(CubeGeometryTier5.faces.length > 0)
          {
             CubeGeometryArray.push(CubeGeometryTier5.clone());
             CubeGeometryTier5.sortFacesByMaterialIndex();
             var Cubemesh = new THREE.Mesh(CubeGeometryTier5,   CubeMaterials); 
             Cubemesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
             Cubemesh.updateMatrix();
             Cubemesh.name = "Tier5";
             scene1.add(Cubemesh);
          }
       };

       // merging geometry for improved performance. 
       function AddCubeGeometry(geom, matrix,tier)
       {
        switch(tier)
          {
           case 1:
            //CubeGeometryTier1.merge(geom, matrix, tier - 1);
            CubeGeometryTier1.merge(geom, matrix);
             break;
           case 2:
             CubeGeometryTier2.merge(geom, matrix,tier - 1);
             break;
           case 3:
             CubeGeometryTier3.merge(geom, matrix,tier - 1);
             break;

           case 4:
             CubeGeometryTier4.merge(geom, matrix,tier - 1);
             break;

           case 5:
             CubeGeometryTier5.merge(geom, matrix,tier - 1);
             break;
            // forty footers 
           case 6:
            //             CubeGeometryTier1.merge(geom, matrix,tier - 1);
             CubeGeometryTier1.merge(geom, matrix);
             break;

           case 7:
             CubeGeometryTier2.merge(geom, matrix,tier - 1);
             break;

           case 8:
             CubeGeometryTier3.merge(geom, matrix,tier - 1);
             break;

           case 9:
             CubeGeometryTier4.merge(geom, matrix,tier - 1);
             break;

           case 10:
             CubeGeometryTier5.merge(geom, matrix,tier - 1);
             break;

           default:
             CubeGeometryTier1.merge(geom, matrix,0);
             break;           
         }
        };





   motioncontrol.position.y = 10;
   motioncontrol.position.x = -50;
   motioncontrol.position.z = 0;
   motioncontrol.rotation.x = 0;

   motioncontrol.rotation.z = motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.cos(0);
   motioncontrol.rotation.x = motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.sin(0);




  function LoadCubes()
   {
     var cnt = 0;
     for(var x = 0; x < 5; x++)
      {
       addCube20(cnt, 0, x * 23.0, 90, 1, true);
       cnt++;
       addCube40(cnt, 10, x * 43, 90, 1, true);
       cnt++;
      }

    };


   // game systems code

   var keyboardControls = (function() {

    var keys = { SP : 32, Q:81, E:69, W : 87, A : 65, S : 83, D : 68, UP : 38, LT : 37, DN : 40, RT : 39 };

    var keysPressed = {};

    (function( watchedKeyCodes ) {
     var handler = function( down ) {
      return function( e ) {
       var index = watchedKeyCodes.indexOf( e.keyCode );
       if( index >= 0 ) {
        keysPressed[watchedKeyCodes[index]] = down; e.preventDefault();
       }
      };
     };
     window.addEventListener( "keydown", handler( true ), false );
     window.addEventListener( "keyup", handler( false ), false );
    })([
     keys.SP, keys.Q, keys.E, keys.W, keys.A, keys.S, keys.D, keys.UP, keys.LT, keys.DN, keys.RT
    ]);


    return function() {

      // look around                    

     if (keysPressed[keys.Q])
     {
         motioncontrol.tiltangle += motioncontrol.bumpdegrees;
         if (motioncontrol.tiltangle < 0)
           motioncontrol.tiltangle += 360;
        var angle = (Math.PI / 180.0) * motioncontrol.tiltangle;
        motioncontrol.rotation.y =  motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.sin(angle);
       }  

      if (keysPressed[keys.E])
       {
         motioncontrol.tiltangle -= motioncontrol.bumpdegrees;
         if (motioncontrol.tiltangle < 0)
          motioncontrol.tiltangle += 360;
           var angle = (Math.PI / 180.0) * motioncontrol.tiltangle;
        motioncontrol.rotation.y =  motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.sin(angle);
       }


     if (keysPressed[keys.W])
       {
        motioncontrol.position.y += motioncontrol.bumpposition;
        if (motioncontrol.position.y > 1000.0)
         motioncontrol.position.y = 1000.0;
       }  

      if (keysPressed[keys.S])
       {
       motioncontrol.position.y += -motioncontrol.bumpposition;
       if (motioncontrol.position.y < 1.0)
        motioncontrol.position.y = 1;
       }




      if(keysPressed[keys.A])
      {
        var angle = Math.atan2(motioncontrol.rotation.x, motioncontrol.rotation.z);
        angle += Math.PI / 180.0 * 90;
        var message = "Angle " + angle * 180/Math.PI;
        motioncontrol.position.z += motioncontrol.bumpposition * Math.cos(angle);
        motioncontrol.position.x += motioncontrol.bumpposition * Math.sin(angle);
       }

      if(keysPressed[keys.D])
      {
        var angle = Math.atan2(motioncontrol.rotation.x, motioncontrol.rotation.z);
        angle += Math.PI / 180.0 * -90;
        var message = "Angle " + angle * 180/Math.PI;
        motioncontrol.position.z += motioncontrol.bumpposition * Math.cos(angle);
        motioncontrol.position.x += motioncontrol.bumpposition * Math.sin(angle);
       }

      // forward  
      if (keysPressed[keys.UP])
      {
        var angle = Math.atan2(motioncontrol.rotation.x, motioncontrol.rotation.z);

        var message = "Angle " + angle * 180/Math.PI;
        motioncontrol.position.z += motioncontrol.bumpposition * Math.cos(angle);
        motioncontrol.position.x += motioncontrol.bumpposition * Math.sin(angle);
       }

      // backward 
      if(keysPressed[keys.DN])
       {
        var deltaX = motioncontrol.rotation.z - motioncontrol.position.z;
        var deltaY = motioncontrol.rotation.x - motioncontrol.position.x;
        // var angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
        var angle = Math.atan2(motioncontrol.rotation.x, motioncontrol.rotation.z);
        angle += Math.PI;
       var message = "Angle " + angle * 180/Math.PI;
        motioncontrol.position.z += motioncontrol.bumpposition * Math.cos(angle);
        motioncontrol.position.x += motioncontrol.bumpposition * Math.sin(angle);
       }

      if(keysPressed[keys.LT])
      {
         motioncontrol.rotationanglezx -= motioncontrol.bumpdegrees;
         if (motioncontrol.rotationanglezx < 0)
          motioncontrol.rotationanglezx += 360;

         var angle = (Math.PI / 180.0) * motioncontrol.rotationanglezx;
         motioncontrol.rotation.x =  motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.cos(angle) - motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.sin(angle);
         motioncontrol.rotation.z =  motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.sin(angle) + motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.cos(angle);

        }
      if(keysPressed[keys.RT])
        {
         motioncontrol.rotationanglezx += motioncontrol.bumpdegrees;
         if (motioncontrol.rotationanglezx > 360)
          motioncontrol.rotationanglezx -= 360;

         var angle = (Math.PI / 180.0) * motioncontrol.rotationanglezx;
         motioncontrol.rotation.x =  motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.cos(angle) - motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.sin(angle);
         motioncontrol.rotation.z = motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.sin(angle) + motioncontrol.distancePointZ * Math.cos(angle);

        }
    };

   })();


   var updateCamera = (function() {

    return function() {

     camera.position.copy(motioncontrol.position);

     camera.lookAt(motioncontrol.rotation);
     var message = "Rotation " + motioncontrol.rotationanglezx + "<BR>";
     message += "X " + motioncontrol.position.x + "<BR>";
     message += "Y " + motioncontrol.position.y + "<BR>";
     message += "Z " + motioncontrol.position.z + "<BR>";

     message += "X " + motioncontrol.rotation.x + "<BR>";
     message += "Y " + motioncontrol.rotation.y + "<BR>";
     message += "Z " + motioncontrol.rotation.z + "<BR>";
     var angle = Math.atan2(motioncontrol.rotation.x, motioncontrol.rotation.z);
     message += "Angle " + angle * 180 / Math.PI + "<BR>";
     message += "Use Arrows w,s,e,d,q,a to navigate<BR>";

     writeToScreen2(message);

    };
   })();


  function render() {
    if(cMaterialCount > 9 && cMaterialCount < 200 && CubesLoaded)
      {
       cMaterialCount = 200;
       LoadCubes();
       DisplayCubes(scene);
      }
     keyboardControls();           
     updateCamera();

     renderer.render( scene, camera );
     requestAnimationFrame( render ); 
   };

  render();

   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do we really need to read hundreds of lines just to answer your question?

Comment: I am new to this and hate asking for help. I am trying very hard to be complete. That is why there is SO much code. Sorry for making the example so long. Will try to make it shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR **Array Mutation and Static Offsets are a dangerous mix**

First, I recommend you post fiddles of some sort of your code. I made one [here](https://jsbin.com/nacebeyeki/edit?js,output) of your example. Second, you could really use some [DRYing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) to shorten and clarify your code. Third, in code of this size, I recommend separating and grouping your code somehow (files, tasks, even comment blocks). Last, in a demo like this, I see no reason to roll your own controls. Check out [Orbit Camera](http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_orbit) or the like that THREE.js offers.

Anyway, I gathered you collect a large number of cubes into 10 'tiers' of THREE.Geometry for rendering purposes. Then on click (~line 180), raycast out, and try to remove just that cube from the geometry. Here's your relevant code:

```
intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(CubeArray);
if(intersects.length > 0)
 {
  if(intersects[0].object.name != null)
   {
    var offset = intersects[0].object.name * 8;
    var offsetfaces = intersects[0].object.name * 12;
    var index = intersects[0].object.name;
    var selectedObject = scene.getObjectByName("Tier1");
    scene.remove(selectedObject);

    CubeArray.splice(index, 1);
    CubeGeometryTier1 = CubeGeometryArray[0];
    CubeGeometryTier1.vertices.splice(offset, 8);
    CubeGeometryTier1.faces.splice(offsetfaces, 12);
    CubeGeometryTier1.faceVertexUvs[0].splice(offsetfaces, 12);

    CubeGeometryArray[0] = CubeGeometryTier1.clone();

    CubeGeometryTier1.sortFacesByMaterialIndex();
    var cmesh = new THREE.Mesh(CubeGeometryTier1,   new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(CubeMaterials));
    cmesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    cmesh.updateMatrix();
    cmesh.name = "Tier1";
    scene.add(cmesh);
   }
  else
   INTERSECTED = null;
 }
```

Here's how I read this snippet:

- Cast out against the CubeArray
- Without a hit something or if it lacks a name, return
- Implict cast some string names (!) to numbers to compute location in Tier
- Remove an object from the scene by the name "Tier1", regardless of any other input
- Set CubeGeometryTier1 to the first index of CubeGeometryArray, regardless of raycast
- Fiddle with now overwritten CubeGeometryTier1 to remove geometry
- Reassign CubeGeometryArray[0] with the changed object of CubeGeometryTier1
- Build a new mesh based on CubeGeometryTier1, call it "Tier1" and dump it back into the scene

I'll admit I haven't entirely traced the hundreds of line where you build your cubes, but this makes little sense to me. Assuming your use of CubeGeometry[Tier|Array] and hard coded names and indices are correct, what really grabs me is the use of **static offsets when you mutate the array**.

You splice CubeArray to remove that 'ghost' cube from getting picked again, but none of the other 'ghost' cubes changed, notably their offsets names, while the geometry that you rebuilt into Tier1 did. Past the spliced cube, all of them index names will be *wrong*.

Here's an example in simpler form:

```js
//set up
var baseArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(i => '' + i);
const getRandomInt = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
};
const pickRandomElementFrombaseArray = () => {
  const pickedIndex = getRandomInt(0, baseArray.length);
  return baseArray[pickedIndex];
};


// operationally equivilent to splicing your Tiers of their geometry
const yankIndex = (value) => {
  //value is a string in this case
  const index = +value;
  if (index < 0 || index > baseArray.length - 1) {
    throw `Unable to remove invalid index ${index}`
  } else {
    baseArray.splice(index, 1);
  }
};


// Run the test until empty or failure
var messages = [`Starting with ${baseArray}`];
while (baseArray.length > 0) {
  const pickedValue = pickRandomElementFrombaseArray();
  messages.push(`Picked element ${pickedValue} to remove`);
  try {
    yankIndex(pickedValue);
    messages.push(`Now array is ${baseArray}`);
  } catch (e) {
    messages.push(`ALERT: ${e}`);
    break;
  }
}

messages.push('Test complete');
const div = $('#div');
messages.map(msg => `<p>${msg}</p>`).forEach(msg => div.append(msg))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Results</h2>
  <div id="div"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Try it a few times. There's only a 0.8% chance the array will be exhausted before an error.

Sneaky errors can creep into code when you are dealing with mutation of arrays. Ignoring restructuring the code entirely, options that spring to mind:

1. **Maintain an offset map on each removal**. Essentially, rebuild each cube's offset on every action. You could do this in the CubeArray or, if creating/mutating 10k heavy THREE.js objects is not to your liking, yet another level of indirection that maps each cube id to an offset in the Tiers
2. **Invisible Objects** Never really remove the geometry (ie, don't splice the Tier array), just hide it. Scale the faces to 0, invisible mat, whatever. This means all the offsets you pre-generate will hold. Downsides are invisible geo isn't free, this won't help if you need to change the scene in other ways, and you'll have to scan the other hits from [thee.raycast](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Raycaster)

Comment: Past the spliced cube, all of them index names will be wrong.I agree with that but still dont understand on the first effort how I remove 2 cubes.I am still very new to this will try and learn to use Fiddle.

Comment: No worries about being new. As for tracking down _why 2 cubes_, I assume either the mouseDown is bouncing or it's some quirk of messing with the THREE.js geometry (which is throwing "THREE.BufferAttribute.copyVector3sArray(): vector is undefined" that I didn't notice before, check the console).  You can chase that down if you want, but it's probably easier to restructure the code to avoid this fault. You can try either of the suggested methods or do some rewrites, neither of which will fit in a comment. And fiddles or jsbins just make it easier for others to see your work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The fault led me to the issue. I needed to modify the face indexes as well. In short if you know the index of the vertices and faces you you can then remove them but then you need to modify the index of the faces which come after the vertices you removed.